# why do I get these errors with my code in this case?

Tags: c++

Sorry if I am doing sth wrong in aksing but I need help, this is my Code:

It is a task for university but I don't have a clue what I am doing wrong.

Maybe the if part?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double a = 0.0;
double b = 0.0;
double c = 0.0;
double s = 0.0;
double flaecheninhalt;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung1 = true;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung2 = true;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung3 = true;
bool flaecheninhaltBerechnenMoeglich = true;

cout << "Im Folgenden soll der Flächeninhalt eines Dreiecks mit von Ihnen gegebenen Seitenlängen berechnet werden.";

do {
    //Nutzereingabe der Zahlen
    do {                                      
        cout << "Bitte geben Sie eine Kommazahl, größer oder gleich 1, für die Seite a ein: ";
        cin >> a;
    } while ( a <= 1 );

    do {
        cout << "Bitte geben Sie eine Kommazahl, größer oder gleich 1, für die Seite b ein: ";
        cin >> b;
    } while ( b <= 1 );

    do {
        cout << "Bitte geben Sie eine Kommazahl, größer oder gleich 1, für die Seite c ein: ";
        cin >> c;
    } while ( c <= 1 );
    
    // Bedingung 1 prüfen
    if ( ( a + b ) > c ) {
        bedingungZurBerechnung1 = true;
    } else {
        bedingungZurBerechnung1 = false;
    }
    
    // Bedingung 2 prüfen
    if ( ( a + c ) > b ) {
        bedingungZurBerechnung2 = true;
    } else {
        bedingungZurBerechnung2 = false;
    }
    
    // Bedingung 3 prüfen
    if ( ( b + c ) > a ){
        bedingungZurBerechnung3 = true;
    } else {
        bedingungZurberechnung3 = false;
    }

    // Prüfen ob Bedingungen zutreffen
    if ( bedingungZurBerechnung1 == true ; bedingungZurBerechnung2 == true ; bedingungZurBerechnung3 == true ) {
        flaaecheninhaltBerechnenMoeglich = true;
    
    } else {
         flaecheninhaltBerechnenMoeglich = false;
    }

    // Berechnung und Ausgeben des Flächeninhalt oder mitteilen, dass das nicht möglich ist
    if ( flaecheninhaltBerechnenMoeglich == true ){
        s = (a+b+c) / 2;
        flaecheninhalt = sqrt {s * ( s - a ) * ( s - b ) * ( s - c )};
        cout << "Der Flächeninhalt beträgt. " << flaecheninhalt << endl;
    } else {
       cout << "Mit den von ihnen erzeugten Zahlen kann leider kein Dreieck gebildet werden. Bitte versuchen sie es erneut." << endl; 
    }
    AlgoViz::sleep(3000); // Kurzes Warten um keine Verwirrung des Nutzers zu erzeugen
    
} while (berechnungFlaecheninhaltMoeglich == false ); //Start von vorne falls Bilden des Dreiecks nicht möglich
```

And these are the erros I get:
and a lot more but all the same...

Am I using the if correcctly?
And whats the problem with cin >> a in the beginning?

```
input_line_14:21:13: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>') and 'double')
        cin >> b;
        ~~~ ^  ~
/opt/tljh/user/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/istream:120:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'double' to 'std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::__istream_type &(*)(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::__istream_type &)' (aka 'basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> > &(*)(basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> > &)') for 1st argument
      operator>>(__istream_type& (*__pf)(__istream_type&))
      ^
/opt/tljh/user/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/istream:222:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'double' to 'long double &' for 1st argument
      operator>>(long double& __f)
```

Comment: Your code needs to be inside a function. Probably int main() since I don't see one in the code provided.

Comment: In C++ code is written inside functions. There's a special function called `main` which is where your program starts. Your errors are happening because you haven't defined any functions. C++ programs are not like scripts which just execute from top to bottom.

Comment: It also helps if you declare your variables as close as possible to their first use location. It means we don't have to track back to find out where they came from, or if they were even declared at all.

Comment: Are you really saying that you are learning C++ at university, but no-one has told you how to write a function? That is amazing. I mean I could believe it of someone teaching themselves, but you're on a university course.

Comment: @john C++ courses in university tend to be astoundingly, if not horrifyingly bad. It's doing a huge disservice to the students, and to the reputation of C++.

Comment: As far as I know I don't need a function bc it's no real c++. someone told me it is compiled to python and back to make it usable and teachable in the beginnigng. everything that happened o far was without using functions. plus. if I put the code in any function it tells me that function definition is not allowed..

Comment: Then you're not actually writing standard C++ and nobody can help without knowing what this Python layer is doing.

Comment: *It's not real C++*. You really should have mentioned that in the question. Hard to help when the language you are using is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you put most, if not all of your code in functions, but there are a few exceptions including global variables, `#include` directives, macros, and others but that is out of scope for this question.

So you just need to put your code in a function, i will assume that you want it in a main function as you are only a beginner.

So you will have your main function that looks like this:

```
int main()
{
  // ... Your code from before
}
```

But you wont put everything in this function, the exception is the header files, these do not belong in functions.
So this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std; // note this is not in main function but could be
```

belongs outside the main function. But the rest:

```
double a = 0.0;
double b = 0.0;
double c = 0.0;
double s = 0.0;
double flaecheninhalt;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung1 = true;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung2 = true;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung3 = true;
bool flaecheninhaltBerechnenMoeglich = true;

cout << "Im Folgenden soll der Flächeninhalt eines Dreiecks mit von Ihnen gegebenen Seitenlängen berechnet werden.";

do {
    //Nutzereingabe der Zahlen
    do {                                      
        cout << "Bitte geben Sie eine Kommazahl, größer oder gleich 1, für die Seite a ein: ";
        cin >> a;
    } while ( a <= 1 );

    do {
        cout << "Bitte geben Sie eine Kommazahl, größer oder gleich 1, für die Seite b ein: ";
        cin >> b;
    } while ( b <= 1 );

    do {
        cout << "Bitte geben Sie eine Kommazahl, größer oder gleich 1, für die Seite c ein: ";
        cin >> c;
    } while ( c <= 1 );
    
    // Bedingung 1 prüfen
    if ( ( a + b ) > c ) {
        bedingungZurBerechnung1 = true;
    } else {
        bedingungZurBerechnung1 = false;
    }
    
    // Bedingung 2 prüfen
    if ( ( a + c ) > b ) {
        bedingungZurBerechnung2 = true;
    } else {
        bedingungZurBerechnung2 = false;
    }
    
    // Bedingung 3 prüfen
    if ( ( b + c ) > a ){
        bedingungZurBerechnung3 = true;
    } else {
        bedingungZurberechnung3 = false;
    }
```

Belongs inside the main function.
You could however declare the variables:

```
double a = 0.0;
double b = 0.0;
double c = 0.0;
double s = 0.0;
double flaecheninhalt;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung1 = true;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung2 = true;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung3 = true;
bool flaecheninhaltBerechnenMoeglich = true;
```

as global but this is not considered best practice. But if you needed them to be global (which is very rare) you would do something like this:

```
double a = 0.0;
double b = 0.0;
double c = 0.0;
double s = 0.0;
double flaecheninhalt;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung1 = true;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung2 = true;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung3 = true;
bool flaecheninhaltBerechnenMoeglich = true;

int main()
{
// rest of code
}
```

But your final program would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
double a = 0.0;
double b = 0.0;
double c = 0.0;
double s = 0.0;
double flaecheninhalt;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung1 = true;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung2 = true;
bool bedingungZurBerechnung3 = true;
bool flaecheninhaltBerechnenMoeglich = true;

cout << "Im Folgenden soll der Flächeninhalt eines Dreiecks mit von Ihnen gegebenen Seitenlängen berechnet werden.";

do {
    //Nutzereingabe der Zahlen
    do {                                      
        cout << "Bitte geben Sie eine Kommazahl, größer oder gleich 1, für die Seite a ein: ";
        cin >> a;
    } while ( a <= 1 );

    do {
        cout << "Bitte geben Sie eine Kommazahl, größer oder gleich 1, für die Seite b ein: ";
        cin >> b;
    } while ( b <= 1 );

    do {
        cout << "Bitte geben Sie eine Kommazahl, größer oder gleich 1, für die Seite c ein: ";
        cin >> c;
    } while ( c <= 1 );
    
    // Bedingung 1 prüfen
    if ( ( a + b ) > c ) {
        bedingungZurBerechnung1 = true;
    } else {
        bedingungZurBerechnung1 = false;
    }
    
    // Bedingung 2 prüfen
    if ( ( a + c ) > b ) {
        bedingungZurBerechnung2 = true;
    } else {
        bedingungZurBerechnung2 = false;
    }
    
    // Bedingung 3 prüfen
    if ( ( b + c ) > a ){
        bedingungZurBerechnung3 = true;
    } else {
        bedingungZurBerechnung3 = false;
    }

    // Prüfen ob Bedingungen zutreffen
    if ( bedingungZurBerechnung1 == true && bedingungZurBerechnung2 == true && bedingungZurBerechnung3 == true ) {
        flaecheninhaltBerechnenMoeglich = true;
    
    } else {
         flaecheninhaltBerechnenMoeglich = false;
    }

    // Berechnung und Ausgeben des Flächeninhalt oder mitteilen, dass das nicht möglich ist
    if ( flaecheninhaltBerechnenMoeglich == true ){
        s = (a+b+c) / 2;
        flaecheninhalt = sqrt(s * ( s - a ) * ( s - b ) * ( s - c ));
        cout << "Der Flächeninhalt beträgt. " << flaecheninhalt << endl;
    } else {
       cout << "Mit den von ihnen erzeugten Zahlen kann leider kein Dreieck gebildet werden. Bitte versuchen sie es erneut." << endl; 
    }
    AlgoViz::sleep(3000); // Kurzes Warten um keine Verwirrung des Nutzers zu erzeugen
    
} while (berechnungFlaecheninhaltMoeglich == false ); //Start von vorne falls Bilden des Dreiecks nicht möglich
}
```

Assuming that `Algo::Viz` was declared elsewhere and `berechnungFlaecheninhaltMoeglich` because otherwise generates a compiler error  as shown in https://www.godbolt.org/z/51fGqjW1P.

You also had a few small errors like calling square root with {} like

```
sqrt{/*...*/};
```

instead of

```
sqrt(/*...*/);
```

Also you had:

```
if(bedingungZurBerechnung1 == true ; bedingungZurBerechnung2 == true ; bedingungZurBerechnung3 == true)
```

instead of

```
if(bedingungZurBerechnung1 == true && bedingungZurBerechnung2 == true && bedingungZurBerechnung3 == true)
```

or

```
if(bedingungZurBerechnung1 == true || bedingungZurBerechnung2 == true || bedingungZurBerechnung3 == true)
```

Semicolons dont belong in if statements until c++17 when you can declare variables. But that is not the purpose that you are using.